# Correct usage of 'following' before listing some points

Tags: sentence-construction

Are all of these sentences valid:

1. The following lists some important points:
2. The followings are some important points:
3. The important points are the followings:

If not, then what is the correct way of using them?

Answer (score 1):

The first one would be the only one I’d consider correct.

“The following” refers to the thing that comes next - a passage, paragraph, section, etc. - and so would never be pluralised as “followings”.

However, “the following lists some important points” doesn’t seem quite right to me, perhaps because “list” is somewhat of a structural term, as in, the following doesn’t list (verb), it is a list (noun). (However, I do think it would be understood and for the most part considered appropriate.)

I’d need more context to say what phrase I’d actually use. Perhaps something like:

> The following is a list of important points.

Or, if not all of the points were considered important:

> The following list provides some important points.

Comment: @Mach So technically, 'followings' is not a valid word, i take it?

Comment: “Followings” is a word, it’s the plural of “following”. You’d mostly hear it in a context where a following means a group of followers. You might have followings from multiple demographics, for example.